# Dividing an integer by an integer is giving me a float

Tags: python, python-3.x

Everything else works fine but except the two

```
People = input("Number of people: ")
Cookie = input("Numnber of cookies: ")
People = int(People)
Answer = int(Cookie) / int(People)
Remain = int(Cookie) % int(People)
print ("Cookies per person: ", Answer)
print ("Cookies returning to the jar: ", Remain)
```

Running the code with the two variable 4(people) and 11(cookies) returns this:

```
Number of people: 4
Number of cookies: 11
Cookies per person:  2.75
Cookies returning to the jar:  3
```

How do I change that 2.75 to just a 2?

Python 3.3

Answer (score 7):

To recover Python 2.X's `int` behaviour here, you can use `//`:

```
>>> 11/4
2.75
>>> 11//4
2
```

`//` works in Python 2 as well, for that matter.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you could also use the more concise:

```
answer, remain = divmod(cookies, people)
```